# Core dump when creating vector from vector range

Tags: c++, vector

Apologies in advance for not having a full set of details but I encountered this at home and am now at work. Also I am a STL newbie, so I am sure my syntax is wrong somewhere.

I am trying to modify the omxplayer subtitle renderer code to word wrap. The input is a vector of InternalChar types where InternalChar is a private struct typedef in the class I am modifying. The code iterates through the vector finding word wrap locations. The code looks like:

"input" is of type std::vector.
"output" is a vector of such vectors.

```
auto start=input.begin()
```

...we then don't (in this particular case) enter a loop which finds word wrap points, creates a vector from a range within "input" and updates "start" appropriately...

```
output[count] = std::vector<InternalChar>(start, input.end())
```

EDIT

I think I may well have been using the following instead of the above:

```
output.push_back(std::vector<InternalChar>(start, input.end()));
```

END EDIT

GDB tells me that the crash occurs on this last line, deep within STL in some "swap" function or something. My first thought was that I needed to use "input.end() - 1" as the end of the range, but that too crashes in identically the same way.

I was also wondering if the problem is that InternalChar doesn't have an assignment operator, but it's a simple struct with a bool member and a char32_t member so surely C++ can work out how to copy from one vector to the newly created one.

Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Many possible reasons, my first guess would be out of bounds access to the `output` vector. I.e. count is < 0 or >= output.size().

Comment: My guess is that `output[count]` is not allocated. The `swap` call probably executes during the assignment since the rhs is a temporary. Either `output` needs to be created with the right size, or you need to use `output.push_back` to append to the vector and grow it automatically. But without more code that is just a guess.

Comment: @Adam Thinking about it, I think I was using push_back rather than indexed access. But suddenly I am not sure. And I haven't pre-allocated any memory, so that may be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Adam Burry and (less so since he said size() rather than capacity()) to John:

The code WAS using [] access and had not previously had any storage allocated to it. Switching to using push_back() which was what I originally intended but didn't actually implement.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators in a vector may become invalid if you add or remove elements as the vector may decide to re-allocate. So if you store `input.begin()` in some variable and later on decide to use it, it is possible that it is no longer valid.

Comment: I am not modifying "input", so that's not my problem. But useful info anyway, thanks!